# I am trying to hide and show a div based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am working on a shopify website.It is a step base cart functionality, And hide and show works after second step The thing here is i am trying to hide and show a div based on button click, So If i select a button one time it hides a div and If i select a button two times it hides another div, But It is not reversing the order.It means if i deselect the button it not showing the div back, it stays hide

Please help me with that
My website url: https://abmw6w36umi6wmd9-8342896758.shopifypreview.com/

Here is my code

```js
 <script>
var clicks = 0;

function myFunction() {
  clicks = clicks+1;
  if(clicks == 1){
    document.getElementById('twoo-step').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('ist-step').style.display = 'none'; 
  }

}
    
    
  </script>

    <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    jQuery(".select_btn_two").click(function () {
        if (count >= 1) {
            jQuery("#twoo-step").hide();
        } else count++

    });

}); 
    
    
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you add more details or rephrase your question?

Comment: In your document ready I don't see you calling my function being called. Also, it looks like clicks will continue to increment. I have some ideas I just need more information on what is going on.

Comment: @banderson he is using `myfunction`, but you can only see it by going to his site.

Comment: Yes, My function being called at Select button, If you go to the step two of the page, You will see

Comment: @Honey People aren't suppose to go to your site to figure out what the problem/error is. You are supposed to post all the relevant code so that we can help you here.

Comment: Yes the whole code i have pasted above, there are individual buttons below each product.so if you select one button a pop up comes out it says one product selected, and if you select two it shows two product, but once you deselect one button it still shows two product selected

Answer (score 0):

I have seen problems like this solved two ways. You could set a variable to true or false based on the click. So like var firstHidden = false. Then myFunction does firstHidden =  !firstHidden. The other way is to use the modulus operator %. If clicks % 2 == 0 there is no remainder and toggle both one way. Else toggle both the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Target the div with a class and if you can't isolate it that way you might need to use nth-child pseudo. Shopify uses jQuery, I believe, but this code can be done with vanilla js with a bit of a rewrite.

Here's my solution, the button works and toggles the div opacity; display none means it's removed from the dom so I didn't opt for that, want to keep the spacing the same.

Toggle a class to control the visibility of the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".clickMe").click(function(){
  $(".hideDiv").toggleClass("hide");
});

});
```

```css
.hide {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Don't ever hide me</div>
<div class="hideDiv">Hide and show this</div>
<button class="clickMe">Click me</button>
```